# Building Chromium's unit tests: generate_fontconfig_caches failed

Tags: chromium, gn, fontconfig

I have been able to build Chromium from source, for Ubuntu using [this guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/105.0.5195.19/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Build-Chromium).

Subsequently, I want to build the unit tests for it. And specifically, I want to build [vaapi_unittest](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a6b6f555210ddbc613ebb90f43e4f1524a5de841/media/gpu/vaapi/vaapi_unittest.cc).

I have not been able to do so. First it failed on missing TTF fonts, but after adding a whole bunch of fonts to `third_party/test_fonts/test_fonts/` I now get this failure: **generate_fontconfig_caches failed with exit code 1**

```
$ autoninja vaapi_unittest
[25/1011] CXX obj/ui/base/x/x/x11_util.o
...
[789/1009] ACTION //third_party/test_fonts/fontconfig:do_generate_fontconfig_caches(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
FAILED: fontconfig_caches/fb5c91b2895aa445d23aebf7f9e2189c-le64.cache-7 
python3 ../../build/gn_run_binary.py generate_fontconfig_caches
generate_fontconfig_caches failed with exit code 1
[802/1009] CXX obj/media/gpu/chromeos/chromeos/video_decoder_pipeline.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can I avoid this error?

Or alternatively: I'm sure vaapi_unittest does not depend on fonts, so how can I prevent it from depending on that font and its font cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the following entry in my `out/Default/args.gn` file:

```
use_bundled_fontconfig = false
```

When I set it to `true` instead, the unit test will compile and link.